# OD mode change from kernel to normal

Tags: ollydbg

I face a problem, when od is loaded and open win32 application, it auto go to kernel mode, can we change to normal mode? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I get you question correctly, you want to change where OllyDbg breaks first when the executable is loaded.

You can change that by going to: `Options` -> `Option...`. And then selecting the `Startup and exit` under the `Debugging`. There you have an option to select where it will stop when executable is loaded.

[image]

You probably have `System breakpoint` selected.

Comment: how did you create the "broken" screenshot effect? Any specific software you used for that? Thanks.

Comment: @0xC0000022L yup, SnagIt - https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html

Comment: How an UM app can go to KM automatically? It can also be done with gimp, free...